# How to use httpclient in net core to do FIFO request to Amazon SQS Queue

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

How to send http request to amazon api gateway that is linked to FIFO queue? I have no issues sending payload via api gateway to normal queue, but with FIFO I am getting bad request error. What would be the correct http request for FIFO request for sqs via api gateway? I am successfully doing it via `amazonsqsclient` but i want to get rid of amazon packages, and do ordinary http request to api gateway url instead.

Are there any examples?

Comment: Do you set message GroupId and DeduplicationId  for the messages you submit?

Comment: i set messagegroupid, but maybe i am building the http request wrong way than the api gateway expects? sqs already had deduplication set to true in aws console. do you have an example in c# of how to build proper request?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any example. How did you setup AWS integration request in api? Do you correctly map to what sqs fifo  expects?

Comment: We cant tell whats wrong, you have not pasted code. Asking for the correct way to do something without bounds tends be counter productive in most cases

Comment: So I guess API gateway -> SQS doesn't work, you have to use lambda as middle man and send payload to queue from lambda as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58985450/access-denied-error-when-trying-to-post-messages-to-sqs

Comment: Lambda proxy would be easier to setup: api->lambda->sqs, then configuring all the integration request mappings in api gateway.